# What year is 1983 set?

Tags: 1983

I have been watching [1983](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7371666/?ref_=nv_sr_1?ref_=nv_sr_1) on Netflix and love it but I am from America. I do not understand their history.

When I was watching this show, it was a bit hard and confusing to understand it because I do not know much about Poland. I do know that the Germany invade there in the 1930's and 40's. Poland was under the communist after that and they had the SB.

Did the movie take place in 1983 or in 20 years later in 2003? When I watched the show, this girl was telling the guy that she would text him. It makes me think that it does not actually take place in 1983.

Comment: The IMDB summary of the show that you link to says "decades after a 1983 terrorist attack".

Comment: Yes it said but the movie also said in 20 years so I calculated that the move was set in 2003 ?

Comment: So can I ask what you are finding confusing? .... you ask 'did the movie take place in 1983 or in 20 years later' when it seems you already have that answer.  I'm now really not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Because the movie was label as 1983, so I was thinking it was playing in 1983 BUT as the movie progress further ..there was one scene the girl is in love with her boyfrend who is a law student and works with the cop who is trying to investigating.   So the girl told her boyfriend I'll text you.  That is when I got confuse.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the movie universe, in 1983 there was a terrorist attack that has stopped all the real-life changes which culminated in the fall of the Iron Curtain. The current action of the movie takes place 20 years later, in **2003**, but there are occasional retrospections looking back to 1983.

The title is, of course, a nod to the [George Orwell book '1984'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four), which describes a world in a perpetual state of war,  omnipresent government surveillance and propaganda.

Since the OP was a bit confused about the dates, let me put them here:

- 1918 - Poland regains independence after 123 years after being
  partitioned between Germany, Austro-Hungarian Empire and Russia
- 1   September 1939 - Second World War starts, Nazi Germany invades Poland
- June 1945 - Soviet-controlled government is formed on the territory
  of the liberated Poland
- 1952 - In the new constitution Poland is officially called "The People's Republic of Poland" (PRL)
- 13 December 1981 - Army declares martial law as a measure to fight the growing anti-Soviet opposition
- 22 July 1983 - The martial law is lifted
- June 1989 - After the wave of strikes, the government decides allows the anti-Soviet opposition to partially participate in the election. The opposition takes 99% of the available seats and in the effect, a first non-communist government is formed, the country is renamed to "Republic of Poland"
- 9 November 1989 The Berlin Wall falls, officially ending the Cold War

Comment: Great answer! You also answered in a truly kind manner! Very commendable!!!